# Find the derivative of $y=\ln^3(3-x+x^2)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find the derivative of $$y=\ln^3(3-x+x^2)$$ We have to use the chain rule, but I am not sure how to think about it when we have more complex functions as in this problem. We can rewrite the function as $$y=\left[\ln(3-x+x^2)\right]^3,$$ so the outermost function is $g(x)=x^3$, right? And its derivative is $g'(x)=3x^2$. Then we have $t(x)=\ln(3-x+x^2)$ and $t'(x)=\dfrac{1}{3-x+x^2}(3-x+x^2)^{'}$ and finally $v(x)=(3-x+x^2)$ with $v'(x)=2x-1$. How do we use that in order to find $y'$? I would be grateful if you explained it in detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try to break it down a bit. So let's set

$$f(x)=\ln^3(3-x+x^2).$$

As you noticed first, we have "some function" to the power of $3$, and so if we set

$$a(x)=x^3$$

and

$$b(x)=\ln(3-x+x^2),$$

then

$$f(x)=a(b(x)).$$

The chain rule then tells us that

$$f'(x)=a'(b(x))b'(x).$$

Now $a'$ we can easily find, as it is just

$$a'(x)=3x^2,$$

but how do we find $b'$? Well, let's do the same thing again, namely notice that it's a composition and break it down. So now let

$$\alpha(x)=\ln(x)$$

and

$$\beta(x)=3-x+x^2.$$

These two functions we know how to differeniate! Indeed

$$\alpha'(x)=\frac{1}{x}$$

and

$$\beta'(x)=-1+2x.$$

Furthermore, the chain rule also tells us now that, as

$$b(x)=\alpha(\beta(x)),$$

we have that

$$b'(x)=\alpha'(\beta(x))\beta'(x).$$

Putting this all together we get that

$$f'(x)=a'(b(x))\alpha'(\beta(x))\beta'(x)=3\ln^2(3-x+x^2)\cdot\frac{1}{3-x+x^2}\cdot(-1+2x)=\frac{3(2x-1)\ln^2(3-x+x^2)}{3-x+x^2}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Another possible approach:

\begin{align*}
y = \ln^{3}(3 - x + x^{2}) & \Longleftrightarrow y^{1/3} = \ln(3 - x + x^{2})\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \frac{y'}{3y^{2/3}} = \frac{2x - 1}{3 - x + x^{2}}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow y' = \frac{3(2x - 1)\ln^{2}(3 - x + x^{2})}{3 - x + x^{2}}
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: May I ask you where does the second line come from? From where did you get $y'$?

Comment: @Kaloyan I differentiated both sides and applied the chain rules to both of them.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I get it. We differentiate both sides of $$y^\frac13=\ln(3-x+x^2)$$ so we get $$\left(y^\frac13\right)^{'}=\dfrac{2x-1}{3-x+x^2}$$ Isn't the LHS equal to $\dfrac13y^{-\frac23}=\dfrac{1}{3y^\frac23}.$ Where does $y'$ come from again?

Comment: @Kaloyan The letter $y$ is a dependent variable. More precisely, it depends on $x$, which is considered to be the independent variable in the exercise proposed. That's how $y'$ appears.

Comment: Maybe I am missing some theory background... what does this have to do with the fact that we are allowed to change the numerator from $1$ to $y'$ when we differentiate both sides of the equality...

Answer (score 1):

You are almost done indeed, by [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule), we have that

$$y=\left(\ln(g(x)\right)^3\implies y'=3\left(\ln(g(x)\right)^2\cdot (\ln(g(x))'\cdot g'(x)=3\left(\ln(g(x)\right)^2\cdot \frac 1 {g(x)}\cdot g'(x)$$

that is in your case

$$y'=3\left(\ln(3-x+x^2)\right)^2\cdot \frac{1}{3-x+x^2} \cdot (-1+2x)$$

Comment: Can you clarify for me where does $\dfrac{g'(x)}{g(x)}$ come from as a multiplier in the application of the chain rule? If $h=f(g(x))$, then $h'=f'(g(x))g'(x)$.

Comment: @Kaloyan I've added a step. The general form in this case is $$y=f(g(h(x))) \implies y'=f'(g(h(x)))\cdot g'(h(x)) \cdot h'(x)$$

Comment: It's the logarithm: if $u$ is a function of $x$, then we have  $$\frac d{dx}\log u=\frac{u'}{u}.$$

Comment: @Kaloyan As Andrew Chain explained the term $\dfrac{g'(x)}{g(x)}$ comes from chain rule applied to $(\ln(g(x))'$ since $(\ln x)'=\frac 1 x$.